# jquery slider - prevent default event on a slider

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working with [superslides](https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides) and i'm trying to add some custom effects on the animations.

I was trying to do so like this:

- on `beforeChange` event, i want to stop the propagation of the event,
  so that the slider doesnt change.
- then, in here, i write my function to animate the elements that are
  inside the slider
- once these animations are done, i then carry on and manually slide to
  the next element

The reason i decided to do this, was because i need the auto play to work, and this was the only idea i could come up with.

The code i have so far is the following:

```
var slider;

slider = $('.home-page-banner');

slider.superslides({
  play: 5000
});

slider.on('animating.slides', function(evt) {
  // tried all of the three below
  evt.preventDefault(); 
  evt.stopPropagation();
  return slider.superslides('stop');
  console.log(slider.superslides('next'));
  slider.superslides('animate', slider.superslides('current'));
  return slider.superslides('stop');
});
```

[example on codepen](https://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/WEedYm)

but unfortunately, it's not working as I'd like to. The slider detects the change, fires the event, changes the slide and only then it stops.

Any help on how to properly achieve this?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use play option.. play 0 [number] Milliseconds before progressing to next slide automatically. Use a falsey value to disable.

Comment: I am actually trying that at the moment, disable auto play, set my custom timeout so that it will pretty much behave the same way but i should have a bit more control over when to change the slide

Comment: Thought of share with you... Just check this out... https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides/blob/0.6-stable/examples/play.html

Comment: @Shiladitya if you want to create an answer i can then select it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` will not work. Use custom Next and Previous buttons and write functions on them. Check [this pen](https://codepen.io/n4nidhinchandran/pen/gxYePp) I forked your pen and modified it to match your needs. Start by clicking next, i used `animate` to create a simple animation.